# Sudden slow down / unusable lag after high memory usage

Tags: ubuntu

I've got a machine which has been running for a fair wile now with Kubuntu (currently 20.10, 5.8.0-29 stock). Its a well spec'd box (Ryzen 3900x, 32GB memory, Sabrent Rocket PCIe4 SSD running on an X570 Gigabyte Aorus Ultra), and on a typical day is sat running Intelij with some big java / angular / node projects (*Lots* of filewatchers, open file handles etc) consuming a fair amount of memory, as well as VMWare and Docker running.

I've noticed recently that when memory usage spikes sometimes (typically in intelij or one of the projects running from within it), the whole system will lag out and never come back. Today when it happened, music bluetooth kept playing a second of audio every 10 seconds or so, the text cursor in intelij would blink (although at an erratic rate) and the mouse cursor would move fine (although clicking on anything would take a minute or so to select). I've never waited more than 10 minutes, but in that time this doesn't appear to clear.

On next boot, I can see nothing suggesting any issues at all in the kernel / other logs.

Beyond a full memory test (going to run overnight), is there anything else I could be investigating to see what is causing this?

`free -h` output:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi        18Gi       556Mi       9.9Gi        12Gi       2.9Gi
Swap:          12Gi       4.1Gi       8.6Gi
```

Comment: Do you have a swap configured? How large is it? How much gets swapped out during heavy operations?

Comment: Swapping could make the system unresponsive for a while, while it takes place. what is the output of `free -h` (ideally when you know the system has all those programs opened, try to stress it out a bit before doing that).

Comment: `free -h` added in main post. Should swapping be that high a priority that it slams the whole system for that long?

Comment: Try installing and enabling `earlyoom`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ArtemS.Tashkinov - Didn't realise  this was how the default OOM killer works. Should I be upping the swap space too?

Comment: SWAP usually *exacerbates* the symptoms when you're lacking RAM. You need more RAM for your tasks.